# issues with creating a new R markdown file

Tags: r, markdown

I am currently using Rstudio for a class that I am taking, and I have been having issues with creating a new R markdown file. I have attached below what shows up whenever I try to do it. I've tried updating my Macbook, and i even attempted to update the software that R-markdown is saying i don't have but the software, will not load for some reason.

[image]

Comment: If it's not letting you install/update those packages try doing it from the base R app, not through RStudio. RStudio can be fussy about updating certain packages.

Answer (score 1):

From the image that you posted here it looks like you are going to need to install the `digest`, `glue`, `highr` and `knitr` packages.

To do that just run the following code in your console:

```r
remove.packages(c("digest","glue","highr","knitr"))
install.packages(c("digest","glue","highr","knitr"))
```